# Installing Windows 7 x64 on a computer with only USB 3 ports

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-installation, usb-3, dism

I am installing Windows 7 x64 on a HP EliteDesk 800 G3 SFF that only has USB 3 and USB Type-C ports.

Initially, upon booting the USB install media, the USB keyboard and mouse wouldn't work - this was because the Windows 7 install media doesn't have USB 3 drivers.

I was able to modify my Windows 7 install media (USB drive) by using `DISM` to include the USB 3 drivers. Following [this guide](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/125921-how-to-add-drivers-manually-to-a-usb-drive-to-install-windows-7-using-a-usb-3-0-port), I downloaded the USB 3 drivers from HP's website and extracted the driver files and embedded them onto the USB install media. I was then able to install Windows 7 successfully.

However, after Windows 7 x64 is installed, I get stuck at the setup screen because the USB keyboard and mouse don't work again - this is because the USB bootable install media had the drivers on it but they weren't installed when the OS was installed so I am stuck with a computer that has Windows 7 installed without USB 3 drivers so I cannot complete the initial Windows setup.

The drive Windows is installed on is a M.2 SSD.

I also checked the BIOS and there is no way to disable USB 3.

**Is there a way to modify the bootable USB media so that it not only runs the USB 3 drivers but also installs them with the OS so I can use them after Windows is installed?**

Or is there another way to do this?

Related issues: [1](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Can-I-disable-USB-3-0-on-Elitedesk-800-G3/td-p/6339235), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/851143/windows-installation-media-cant-detect-keyboard-and-mouse), [3](http://codeabitwiser.com/2014/03/how-to-install-windows-7-with-only-usb-3-0-ports/).

Comment: Does the BIOS allow an install over the network? This article may help https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-install-any-version-windows-other-network-computers

Comment: Yup, I can do a PXE boot. If I prepare an image for a PXE boot can I include the drivers I need in that image? I haven't read the link you've provided for me yet so forgive me if that is covered on that page, I am going to read it now.

Comment: You could try booting into recovery from the same image and installing the driver https://superuser.com/questions/531594/windows-how-to-install-driver-from-recovery-command-prompt

Comment: Actually I am not sure if doing a PXE boot will work around your USB 3.0 driver missing in the Windows 7 install issue.  Here is a utility and workaround from Intel https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/intel-nuc-kits/000017241.html  and this article mentions updating both the boot and the install so I was wondering if you had done both https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-install-windows-7-on-a-pc-with-only-usb-3-0-ports/

Comment: @RichardChambers Yup I updated both the boot.wim and install.wim (just verified this)

Comment: @user5226582 I booted from the USB with Windows 7 on it and launched the recovery console and opened command prompt and I used pnputil to import all necessary inf files for the USB 3 drivers. Restarted and booted into Windows and the keyboard / mouse are still not working unfortunately.

Comment: @RichardChambers I tried to use that Intel tool yesterday with the boot.wim and install.wim and it said it was successful but it didn't work. When I would boot the USB drive the keyboard and mouse wouldn't work however when I ran through the manual process with DISM I was able to get the keyboard and mouse to work when booting from the USB, just cannot use the keyboard and mouse once Windows is booted from the SSD.

Comment: Does the machine have PS/2 ports on the back for a keyboard or mouse?

Comment: @TylerH Nope, no PS/2 ports. Just 10 USB ports (6 appears to be USB 3, 4 appear to be USB 2 but they don't work without the driver) and 1 USB Type-C

Comment: can you use remote desktop after installing Windows to install the drivers?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc No, I cannot. The CPU is vPro enabled but I do not have any licensing for that. I cannot use remote desktop because I haven't assigned a computer name to the machine yet (this is the step I am stuck on because I cannot use the keyboard/mouse to give it a name). I also tried a KVM switch that I have here and that didn't work.

Comment: Get a PCIe / USB 2.0 card that's supported by the built-in drivers...?

Comment: This is not a definitive solution, but you could boot an Ubuntu live and use it to download and extract the drivers in the System32 / SysWOW64 folders

Comment: @JorgeeFG I booted with the Windows USB drive and went to the recovery console (command prompt) and I attempted to install the drivers that way using pnputil but that didn't work. pnputil said it was successful in installing the drivers but when I booted the OS the keyboard and mouse still didn't work. Not sure if this is worth noting or not but when the keyboard is connected to the USB port not even the num lock or caps lock lights come on (they come on when the keyboard is functional).

Comment: I don't have any complete nice solution as the other guys, but I just wanted to say that you should never download drivers from OEM website (unless the OEM itself is the manufacturer, like say BIOS). I read your PC should be using Q270 chipset, so I think you should try to use its latest USB driver version listed [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/software/chipset-software.html)

Comment: When you used the dism tools in the recovery console, did you remember to specify the drive in the commands? I did this once (with storage drivers having changed from IDE to RAID) and forgot to specify the target OS meaning it installed the drivers only in the recovery console ram image and not to the actual OS.

Comment: You could try from the recovery console: `dism /Image:C:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:D:\ /Recurse` - replace ``C:\`` with the drive that has Windows on it, and ``D:\`` with the drive that has the USB 3.0 drivers on it. That's what worked for me to get RAID drivers installed on an otherwise unbootable OS.

Comment: When you say you checked the BIOS — did you see an option for xHCI/EHCI?

Comment: @Bob [there's none](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05386798#page=77)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I successfully installed Windows 7 on a laptop with a USB 3.0 root hub by using [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/).

It will allow you to insert the USB 3.0 driver inside your Windows 7 ISO.

**NB:** You don't need to buy a license for NTLite, the free version is enough for this use.

Comment: NTLite worked wonders. I downloaded and included the Intel Chipset Support and Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Drivers in the image and it worked! I must have slipstreamed the wrong inf files when I made my original attempt. Thank you for your answer and everyone else for their input.

Comment: @qroberts Are you adding the exe files of drivers or they must be in extracted form as inf/cat/etc. types?

Answer (score 34):

There is a tool for exactly this case [supplied by intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility). It slipstreams the drivers into the installation media in a way that it will also work once installed (I only tested it with an EliteDesk 800G2 SFF but I doubt it has changed that much). Be careful to chose the right version to download, there is a different one for Win7 and Win8 or higher.

Also the tool is a little finicky, you really have to have the image on a usb drive it can not be unpacked into a folder for some reason.

EDIT: As it seems intel removed their own tool because it did not work all the time. [They now recommend](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000017241/mini-pcs.html) to use a tool by gigabyte in cases where PS2 devices do not work. It can be found on [this page](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170X-Gaming-G1-rev-10#support-dl-utility) and is named Windows USB Installation Tool. I have no experience with this tool but it is the official recommendation at the moment.

Comment: I attempted this yesterday using a USB drive that has a Windows image on it and the tool said it was successful but when I would go to boot the USB drive the keyboard and mouse still wouldn't work. I was able to get the keyboard and mouse working using the manual DISM method linked to in my original question however the keyboard and mouse won't work once I boot Windows.

Comment: In that case try both. Prepare your image using the Intel tool **and** do it the manual way. This way you'll have the drivers working during installation and, hopefully, also have them installed.

Comment: That's very strange. I would recommend trying the second tool on a different OS but I'm pretty sure I used both tools successfully already. Sadly our G3 shipments keep getting delayed so I cannot test with that, Another more tedious workaround could be inlcuding the full driver and running it via an Autounattend.xml file (either in a RunSynchronous step or use such a step to modify setupcomplete.cmd)

Comment: What also just came to my mind. Is this a sky lake or a kaby lake G3? If it's kaby lake (which intel refuses to fully support in windows 7 god knows why) they might just not want to support it with their tool

Comment: FYI, this link is broken, does anyone have an updated link?

Comment: It seems intel withdrew the tool because it sometimes did not work but on their faq for the nuc https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000017241/mini-pcs.html they suggest to use a tool by gigabyte instead which can be found here: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170X-Gaming-G1-rev-10#support-dl-utility (search for Windows USB Installation Tool) I never tried this so I am not 100% sure how well it will work but it is intels official recommendation...

Answer (score 17):

An alternative to injecting drivers is checking your UEFI/BIOS for a legacy USB mode.

This, as I understand it, presents the peripherals directly to the operating system (perhaps as if they were plugged in via ps/2). Once windows is fully installed, you should be able to go back into BIOS and disable that option.

This question has more information on this mode; [What does "Legacy USB Mouse" support in a BIOS mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/303365/what-does-legacy-usb-mouse-support-in-a-bios-mean)

Answer (score 6):

Besides using DISM to integrate the drivers into BOTH boot.wim and install.wim (as Xyf already posted) there is another trick that usually works:

During the Win7 setup there is the possibility to load extra drivers (to get extra mass-storage drivers on-board).
What most people don't realize is that this can load other drivers too as long as they are suited for whatever hardware is in the system.
And drivers loaded at this point will automatically be installed to the new OS.

It isn't guaranteed to work (I have never been able to establish exactly what makes a driver work or not at this point) but it is certainly a lot quicker than a second session with DISM if it does happen to work.

Comment: in the XP era people often use this to load SATA drivers after loading the installer

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, but as of Vista the mechanism is a lot better. You don't need a special (floppy -based) version of the driver anymore. Any regular INF file based driver setup will do and you can load it from any media that is readable at boot time.

Answer (score 5):

From the [specifications](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA6-9331EEE&doctype=data%20sheet&doclang=EN_GB&searchquery=&cc=uk&lc=en):

```
Front: 
    1 SD 4 card reader (optional);
    1 USB Type-C™; 
    2 USB 3.1 Gen 1; 
    1 USB 2.0; 
    1 USB 2.0 (fast charging); 
    1 Headphone connector; 
    Universal audio jack with CTIA headset support
Back: 
    1 audio line in; 
    1 RJ-45; 
    1 power connector; 
    1 audio out; 
    2 DisplayPort™; 
    2 USB 2.0; 
    4 USB 3.1 Gen 1; 
    3 optional ports
```

It appears that your machine *should* have USB2.0 ports.  I would use them.

If not, can you get inside the machine?  It will probably still have the USB2.0 headers internally, and you can use a cheap adaptor [like this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-6in-USB-2-0-Cable/dp/B000IV6S9S) to connect your keyboard for the installation process.

Comment: I've tried every USB port on the machine, I will try cold booting and testing each port instead of switching ports while it's turned on.

Comment: The USB 2 ports are clearly labelled both on the outside of the case and inside on the motherboard however none of these ports are working once I am in the Windows installation. They work when I have the drivers installed on the boot media however.

Comment: The keyboard (especially a wired one) should still work or how would you access the BIOS/CMOS screen? If somehow you can access the the BIOS setup, then make sure "Legacy USB support" or similar is enabled.

Comment: Frequently on modern motherboards "USB 2.0" ports are actually placed behind a USB 3.0 root hub. So you still have to have the driver for the USB 3.0 hub installed to get them to work even though the ports only have USB 2.0 connections externally. As such the win 7 install won't see the USB 2.0 ports because it doesn't have the hub driver.

Comment: @TomCarpenter that would explain it.  It is also a little (imho) stupid, as USB3.0 is backwards compatible, and downgrading to USB2.0 only restricts usage.  In that case, I would follow Alan's comment.

Comment: Recent intel chipsets present all the USB ports (whether 2.0 or 3.0) as logically behind an XHCI controller which win7 can't talk to out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

The install media has 2 images:

1. boot.wim
2. install.wim.

`Boot.wim` handles the initial install step (selecting drive and expanding install.wim onto it) and then the setup takes over from the expanded files.

You need to add the USB drivers with DISM to both images.

Comment: That is how i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The process you're looking for is called slipstreaming and it allows you to cram a bunch of things into a windows setup image including drivers, service packs and even applications. It's the same technique that OEMs use for creating custom windows installs for laptops and embedded devices. You can improve the process with additional tools like AutoIT to automate additional setup steps.

Personally though I found the whole process exhausting (like just about any windows configuration task) but it may be your only option. There are tools out there which claim to simplify the process as well.

You'll probably need an existing working Windows 7 machine to create the slipstream image on.

Note that you used to be able to install needed drivers via a floppy by pressing F6 during the install process. Obviously that doesn't help much when modern computers don't have a floppy drive.

Answer (score 0):

If it comes to the worst, you can always put a USB2 port card in the PCI slot. The ones I tried had built-in support in Windows. Besides that, your machine has a card reader. Depending on how it's connected internally, it may be on a USB2 header and have built-in support. You could then put the Windows 7 installer onto a card.
Or just use a USB header connected to your motherboard near the power/reset jumpers. It appears to be the yellow one just below the blue SATA connectors. Mind the polarity; if you connect it backwards, you'll fry the flash drive. Don't say I didn't warn you.