# BSOD & Windows 7 USB repair disk errors

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb

I have a dual boot machine (Windows 7 Ultimate & Ubuntu which uses GRUB as bootmanager and is Windows as entry). I just recently added a third OS to (Windows 10 Pro). THings were running nicely, but at some point my Windows 7  installation became corrupted. While booting up Win7 I am getting a [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death) after the Windows logo shows up with the error:

**0x0000006B: PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED** 
which is described in detail [HERE](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0x0000006b/)

**The next part of this question deals with how I have attempted to create and use a repair disk in hopes to resolve the BSOD issue, but this may not even solve the issue. I am ultimately looking for a way to fix the BSOD error described above and any replies that lead to this BSOD being solved will be marked as the answer.**

Since I do not have my Windows 7 installation disk anymore, I decided to try and use the [Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) & the [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) bootbale disk creator to create a WIndows 7 repair install disk to access the repair functions.

While the startup USB disk is showing that 'Windows is loading Files' at startup the process shows the error:
[image]

This error message is described in detail [HERE](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000225/)
At that site it is mentioned that error 0xc0000225 is usually from a bad BCD which I attempted to correct using EasyBCD but it made no difference as I am still getting the error and still capable of booting into my other operating systems.

I can skip past this error but get a new one on the next screen that loads:
[image]

The error message 0xc0000098 is described in detail [HERE](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000098/). Again, this looks like a bad or missing BCD, but I am confused about this because I am still able to boot into my operating system.

Could there be something wrong with the way I am formatting the Windows Recovery disk that might cause the recovery disk not to load properly? I have tried using both FAT32 and NTFS, as well as using GPT & MBR (MBR wont work at all).

Comment: Which motherboard are you using? Or rather, which kind of USB port? Windows 7 natively shipped with USB2 drivers and no support for USB3. So booting win7 from USB usually work for the first part and then crashes unless you inject USB3 drivers.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1256103/installing-windows-7-x64-on-a-computer-with-only-usb-3-ports

Comment: GA-Z170N-Gaming 5 (rev. 1.0) | Motherboard, Like I said, the disk is now loading ok but Windows install wont get past the 0xc0000225 error.

Comment: I had the same issue a while ago when I installed Windows 10 alongside Windows 8.1: all of a sudden, after updating Windows 10, I couldn't boot Windows 8.1 at all, with roughly the same error message (can't remember exactly, though), and in the end, I simply removed Windows 8.1 from my PC, which, I suspect, was Microsoft's plan all along. I *think* (tinfoil hat on) that MS has devised a stratagem to discourage users from keeping on dual-booting two different versions of Windows (one of them being Win10) on the same PC, and edited the MBR/EFI accordingly. I may be right, or right, or both...

Comment: The BCD is in `C:\boot\bcd`, try to return it from backup. If none, boot from the Windows 7 boot media into Command Prompt mode, rename it via `ren D:\boot\bcd bcd.old` (the disk may be called D but anyway not C) then run `bcdboot.exe D:\Windows /s C:`.

Comment: @harrymc As the original post explains, there are several errors when trying to use Win7 boot media. I can however access the old Win7 C: drive (now named W;) via Windows 10 explorer. Searching it this way though shows no `W:\boot\bcd` directory.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Anyway, I'm not saying to reinstall Windows 7, but to use it to boot into the Command Prompt. See [this method](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/#Fix_the_MBR_in_Windows_7) steps 1-7.

Comment: @harrymc I cant follow any of those steps as I dont have a DVD drive and the errors described above prevent me from loading the USB WIn7

Comment: The same would work from a USB. It's unlikely that you can't boot from USB into Command Prompt, since this does not use the hard disk at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a real helpful answer, the only recourse I had was to abandon using Windows 7 and get Windows 10. I really wanted to keep Win7 but it turns out that this error was unrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

In UEFI boot mode, the boot process is as follows: UEFI firmware > Bootmgfw.efi > \Boot\BCD > winload.efi > ntoskrnl.exe.

> Therefore, if the BCD file has no operating system entry, the boot process will be stopped and 0xc0000098 error occurs.
>
> Another reason for 0xc0000098 error is an installed incompatible hard drive driver.

I feel bcd has to be manually fixed.

As u can access the old Win7 C drive, try running these commands on the Command Prompt in order.
This would try to rebuild your bcd that may clear the 0xc0000098 error.

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

However this still doesn't solve your full problem but if this works atleast you can try all the solutions that requires a bootable USB.
Hope this helps!

Comment: These commands can also be run from a Windows Recovery command prompt run from a windows USB installer

Comment: why are there 2 answers getting 100 points for the bounty?