# I can't enable legacy boot mode in my Noblex SF20BA; the option does not show up

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

I need to enable legacy boot mode in order to install Windows 7 as dual boot with Windows 10.

I already have a bootable Windows 7 USB drive; which does not boot because I can't enable legacy boot mode.

Here, 2 pictures of my BIOS settings:

[image: Pic 1: Boot tab]

[image: Pic 2: Secure boot menu]

It is clear that I need to enable legacy boot mode and for that I need assistance.

Please, tell me how to proceed.

Comment: It's not necessary to enable Legacy (CSM) in order to install Windows 7.  Windows 7 supports UEFI mode. You would have to disable Secure Mode, which is separate from UEFI mode, it is required by Microsoft to allow Secure Boot to be disabled in order to install Windows on that device. Your images are inaccessible.  Use the upload image function of the question editor to upload your files.

Comment: hello @Ramhound, i see my question has been edited which is great.

Comment: Secure boot is disabled, what could be preventing my USB drive from booting?

(sorry for the double mention) @Ramhound

Comment: Since Secure Boot is already disabled you can simply install Windows 7 on your device.  If the hard is newer, or only has a USB 3 port, you should expect problems with installing Windows 7 and/or with device compatibility with Windows 7 in general.  What could prevent Windows 7 from booting from a flash storage device, is if that flash storage device, is plugged into a USB 3.2 Gen 1 (also known as USB 3) port. Windows 7 does not support being installed from a USB 3 device unless the necessary drivers are added.

Comment: Ah, I see!

The USB drive itself does not boot; however, when running setup.exe from within the OS, I'm asked to load "Intel SD Host Controller" drivers. So, yeah, driver issue.

The device itself is a USB 3.2 drive, and my computer has both 3.2 and 2.0 USB ports.

If I get an USB 2.0 drive, will the installation proceed as expected?

PD: I've been searching for those drivers online, to no avail.

@Ramhound

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1256103/installing-windows-7-x64-on-a-computer-with-only-usb-3-ports) are the instructions to add USB 3 driver support to the Windows 7 instalation environment. If you connect a USB 3.2 device to a USB 2.0 port it should be detected as a USB 2.0 device. Recall that USB 3.2 is simply the renamed protocol "USB 3.0", I am under the assumption, that it's actually a USB 3.2 Gen 1 port.

Comment: The process of adding the drivers is quite detailed and simple, but my problem is that I cannot find the drivers for this device. I've contacted the support number via whatsapp. I'll let you know about any further details.

PD: This computer has built-in keyboard and touchpad, so operating them won't be an issue because of the USB drivers. There are available drivers for this device in the driverpack website, but as far as I know, no USB 3.0 drivers are available online.

@Ramhound

Comment: The [Windows USB Installation Tool](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170X-Gaming-G1-rev-10/support#support-dl-utility) should solve the problem for you, but using the USB 2.0 ports with your current device, should resolve the driver issue skipping the need to modify the Windows 7 ISO to include USB 3.0 drivers.

Comment: Then what prevents the usb drive to boot? It's not even recognized by the system, it's just skipped.

For clarification, I get the driver error when running setup.exe while the OS (Windows 10) is running. And on the USB 2.0 port. Never been able to boot it properly.

@Ramhound

Comment: So you likely have two problems, the USB 3.0 driver issue, and the fact your system's boot order isn't properly configured. You likely want to bump the USB Key to the top so it's the first thing the system sees.  I assume you have burned the updated and modified ISO on the flash media that includes the USB 3.0 driver?

Comment: I found a driver pack for this device with 214 different drivers which are currently being written to boot.wim. I'm still doing this so it's not a good time to reboot.

I didn't burn the image myself, I paid someone who did it for me. It's apparently a system image of Windows 7 Ultimate. 

The boot order has all 4 USB options above the Windows Boot Manager, so the boot order is not the issue. 

Should I try to boot the USB drive again after updating the drivers?

@Ramhound

Comment: Why did you pay somebody to burn a Windows 7 ISO? I hope you can get a refund considering, even if you did boot to the installation environment, it would have been wrong.

Comment: because I don't have access to the original ISO files
@Ramhound