# Is there a way to install Windows 7 on a motherboard that only supports Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, desktop-computer

Is there a way to install Windows 7 on a motherboard that only supports Windows 10? I need to install Windows 7 first so I can directly upgrade from it to Windows 10. There are some features that I want to carry on to Windows 10 from Windows 7. I am using an ASUS ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING ATX AM4 Motherboard.

Update:
I loaded a Windows 7 install DVD, but when it loaded, my mouse and keyboard didn't work. I used this guide: [Windows installation media cant detect keyboard and mouse](https://superuser.com/q/851143/1087482), but it still didn't help. I probably missed a setting believing it is not there. I'm guessing that I have to borrow another computer and make a Windows 7 USB install using ASUS EZ installer.

Update 2:
I was able to install Windows 7, but I couldn't find the drivers that allowed me to connect to the internet.

Comment: What Win7 features specifically are you looking for?  There are numerous ways to hack them into Win10 if that's all you're after.

Comment: @nickylego10 - You received feedback to your other question, but never provided a response, suspect your tile issue is caused by the ISO that was used.  Windows Update on Windows 7 is disabled after a certain generation of Intel/AMD processors (exact generation escapes me)

Comment: Unless the manufacturer provides Windows 10 drivers for Networking (wired and wireless), video and audio, then you are not likely to succeed installing Windows 7.  That is why we are suggesting you use a virtual machine until you can upgrade your apps or find new ones.

Comment: Video drivers that support Windows 7 is easy AMD/Nvidia both support it.  Intel does not for their GPUs (8th+ display drivers only support Windows 10). Networking/Bluetooth/Audio is a different story all together, OEM motherboard manufactures simply don’t bother with Windows 7, due to the fact Windows update wont work on the newer generation of CPUs (they would get part of blame if they attempted support)

Comment: @John Yes, the motherboard includes wifi and networking support.

Comment: @Ramhound I posted a comment on that post just now.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind jumping through some hoops to use it:

Install Windows 10.

Install VMWare or some other similar program that allows you to use virtual machines.

Install Windows 7 inside a virtual machine.

I'm writing this inside a virtual machine running Windows 7, other than the menu bar that comes down if I go within a couple of pixels of the top of the screen it behaves just like a normal Windows 7 instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find hardware that suppports Windows 7
2. install Windows 7 there (do not activate it) and do what You have to do with it.
3. When You are ready upgrade it to Windows 10
4. Take an image of that, Win 10 OS, You could use Acronis or [Microsoft imaging technologies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-deployment-scenarios-and-tools)
5. Go to your desired Workstation and: **a)** Try to apply it like it is and later if You manage to boot into your OS, install correct drivers **b)** Prepare image (while offline) with correct drivers and apply it to Your desired Workstation

Or just go with the VM option mentioned in other aswers. Windows 10 supports Hyper-V by default(You just need to activate that feature).