# Keyboard not responding on the BIOS/Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, bios

I have been trying to install Windows 7 on my new PC but, at first try, the keyboard wouldnt respond during the installation process. The keyboard and mouse did respond on the BIOS, though.

Following [this advice](https://superuser.com/questions/851143/windows-installation-media-cant-detect-keyboard-and-mouse), I first tried unplugging and replugging the keyboard during the install, and failing to improve the situation, I disabled the legacy USB on the BIOS to try it again, but not only did this not solve the problem on the install screen of windows 7, the keyboard and mouse now won't respond on the BIOS either, making it impossible to switch it back.

I have tried every USB port I could but none of them give any different result.

The motherboard is a Gigabyte Z390 Aorus Elite, keyboard is a Rii RK100, mouse is some wireless HP mouse.

Edit : managed to get the keyboard working again by resetting the BIOS, so hopefully this should be easier by now

Comment: How new is the computer? Windows 7 cannot be installed on new computers.

Comment: Brand new for Christmas, so that may indeed be an issue

Comment: @John - That isn’t entirely true.  Windows Update on newer hardware will be disabled but in most cases it can be installed.  There are also ways to get those updates on the system.

Comment: @Slereah - It sounds like a USB firmware option.  Make sure your only using USB 2 devices unless you streamlined USB 3 drivers onto the Windows 7 ISO

Comment: Try installing Windows 10 and see if that installs

Comment: The board has a jumper to clear the bios settings. Please read the manual for more information.

Comment: Already managed to reset it (couldn't find the jumper though so I just removed the battery for a bit), so only the keyboard issue for windows 7 remains

Comment: Win7 is missing drivers for USB 3.0. You have to add the drivers "slipstream". See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000017241/intel-nuc.html

Comment: Your motherboard is very new and only has [drivers](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-ELITE-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) for Windows 10 64bit. I suggest installing Windows 10. If you want Windows 7, install it inside a virtual machine.

Comment: Windows 7 is dead in a week or so, so Windows 10 is the way forward at this point